# Wrong output in binary search

Tags: c, function, sorting, binary-search

I am using binary search algorithm to find a number in a predefined array, but if i am entering the value already in an array i am getting correct answer, but on entering a value not in an array like 101,100,121 i am just getting number 10 as output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int binarysearch(int A[],int key);

 int main()
 {
    int key,answer;
    int A[10]={0,5,8,10,12,14,15,18,19,21};
    scanf("%d",&key);
    answer=binarysearch(A,key);
    if (answer!=-1)
    {
        printf("%d",answer);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("NOT FOUND");
    }
}

int binarysearch(int A[],int key)
{
    int i;
    int h,l,m;
    h=10;
    l=0;

    while(l<=h)
    {
        m=(h+l)/2;
        if(A[m]==key)
        {
            return m;
        }
        else if(key<A[m])
             {
                 h=m-1;
             }
             else
             {
               l=m+1;
             }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code, it's ununderstandable.

Comment: use `h=9` instead of `h=10` because array elements are from `0` to `n-1`.Even without changing, your code works for me.http://ideone.com/W6hWZI

Comment: @gauravsehgal it worked for a number within the range, but not for one above the range.

Comment: For what number its not working for you?

Comment: for every number that is not in the array

Comment: @gauravsehgal it worked for a number within the range, but not for one above the range. For example `11` is `NOT FOUND`, but `101` is at index `10` as OP says.

Comment: I checked it again.I am getting `NOT FOUND` for `101`.Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition

```
while(l<=h)
```

to

```
while ( l < h )
```

And change this code snippet

```
    else if(key<A[m])
         {
             h=m-1;
         }
```

the following way

```
    else if(key<A[m])
         {
             h = m;
         }
```

The function could be defined like

```
int binarysearch( const int A[], int n, int key )
{
    int l = 0;
    int h = n;

    while ( l < h )
    {
        int m = ( h + l ) / 2;

        if ( A[m] == key )
        {
            return m;
        }
        else if( key < A[m] )
        {
            h = m;
        }
        else
        {
            l = m + 1;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

And called like

```
answer=binarysearch( A, 10, key );
```